# button to open specific accordion tab

Tags: javascript, tabs, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

i'm trying to create a button or link that opens a specific accordion tab, here is my accordion structure:

```
  <div class="tabs">
  <div class="tabs-header">
  <div class="border"></div>

  <ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" tab-id="1">Home</a></li>

  LINK HERE to open Tab 2
  LINK HERE to open Tab 3


  <li><a href="#tab-2" tab-id="2">Symptom Checker</a></li>


  <li><a href="#tab-3" tab-id="3">Locator</a></li>
  </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="tabs-content">
  <div tab-id="1" class="tab active"></div>
  <div tab-id="2" class="tab"></div>
  <div tab-id="3" class="tab"></div>
  </div>
```

I'm guessing there will be a onclick event I can apply to a button? i've tried:

```
 <a href="#tab-2" tab-id="2">Symptom Checker </a>
```

but nothing happens other than updating the URL

Answer (score 2):

you can use

`$('your_button').on('click',function(){
$( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", 1 );
});`

for tab2 and

`$('your_button').on('click',$( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", 2 );})`

for tab3

or you can use onclick property

`<a onclick="$( '#accordion' ).accordion( 'option', 'active', 1 )">Click here for tab2</a>`

[See a working demo here.](https://jsfiddle.net/4xxo1t6h/1/)

source http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

Comment: Many thanks for your reply - unfortunatly when I click the button nothing happens and when I click the link I nothing happens again and get the following error@ .accordion is not a function(…)

Comment: fixed it...had to adjust the javascript:
`code`
      function changeTab1() {
       var getTabId = $('.tabs-header .active a').attr('tab-id');
      $('.tab').stop().fadeOut(300, function () {
      // Remove Class
       $(this).removeClass('active');
       }).hide();

        $('.tab[tab-id=' + 2 + ']').stop().fadeIn(300, function () {
        // Add Class
        $(this).addClass('active');
        animateTabHeight();
        });
        }`code`

Comment: You use well accordion of jquery ui ??? Because I simply took over the function found in the doc I tried it and it works